# How to get the value of JSON Key when returned from API

Tags: json, angular

My API returns a JSON object to angular function

I need to fetch the value of the key in that JSON.
If I print the value directly on the console, there is no error.

## **My Angular Code :**

```
submit() : void {
    console.log("FORM SUBMITTED")
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.register.value, undefined, 2));
    this._registerService.register(this.register.value)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("DATA : ", JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
        console.log("Status : " + data.status);
        if (data.status == "duplicate") {
          console.log("DUPLICATE");
        } else if (data.status == "success") {
          console.log("SUCCESS");
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("ERRORrrr : ", JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        this._router.navigate(['/500']);
      }
    )
  }
```

In the above code 
**console.log("DATA : ", JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));**
 Works Fine.
It shows the data :
[image]

But If I try to fetch the value of "status" in "data",

```
console.log("Status : " + data.status);
```

It gives error :

```
 error TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

I need to use the value of **status** in **if** statement

Please help in getting the value of data.status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that the object which was returned was an associative array.
So I was able to parse the associative array like : 
console.log(data["status"]);

and I was able to convert this array to JSON by :
let dataJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

After this conversion I could access the JSON Key value by :
console.log(dataJson.status);

Answer (score 1):

Your `.register` method seems to be returning a `Observable<object>`, therefore the TS compiler gives you this error. Perhaps it's better to make it a generic method:

```
register<T>(body: any) { 
  return this._http.post<T>(
    'localhost:3000/register',
    body,
    { observe: 'body' }
  ).catch(this.handleError); 
}
```

Which you can call in your component:

```
this._registerService.register<RegisterData>(this.register.value).subscribe((data) => {
  if (data.status) {
    // this will not throw a compiler error anymore as it will be of type RegisterData
  }
});
```

with the interface being:

```
export interface RegisterData {
  status: string;
  summary: string;
  details: string;
}
```

Comment: My register function is a part of service "register(body: any) {
    return this._http
      .post('http://localhost:3000/register', body, { observe: 'body' })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }"

Comment: @Ashish I've updated how you should make your register method generic. Also, i strongly advise you to update your rxjs version

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of rxjs you use, but in the current version you have to catch errors of Observables with [catchError()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError).

This would be my solution:

```
  register(body: any): Observable<{status: string, summary: string, details: string}> {
    return this._http.post(
           'localhost:3000/register', body, 
           {observe: 'body'}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: There is no error in Service. Problem is that the service returns the JSON object to the COMPONENT. and the component is not able to get the internal KEY VALUE of the object